# For constant $a$, find all real $u$ satisfying $u^4-2au^3+u^2(a^2+1)-2au+(a^2-1)=0$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> If $a$ is a constant and $u$ is a real number satisfying
> $$u^4-2au^3+u^2(a^2+1)-2au+(a^2-1)=0$$
> determine all possible real values of $u$.

I tried thinking of some polynomials in $a$ for doing this since the coefficients are a bit intriguing, but that doesn't help much actually.

Comment: I'm no expert, but I would start with this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quartic_function#Ferrari's_solution

Comment: Thanks for the reply but the method seems quite daunting,i think there might be some clever manipulations to solve this one without much sweat.

Comment: As a total aside, the title of this question sure seems like a spam subject to me. :-)

Comment: The equation can be written as $$(u^2+1)(u-a)^2=1$$ For real $u$, the first factor makes me want to write $u=\tan t$ (for $-\pi/2\leq t\leq\pi/2$) so that we have $$\sec^2t\,(\tan t-a)^2=1\quad\to\quad\tan t\pm\cos t=a$$ This doesn't seem any easier to solve. However, since $f_{\pm}(t)=\tan t\pm\cos t$ is an increasing function with range $(-\infty,\infty)$, we know that $f_\pm(t)=a$ has exactly one solution for each real $a$. So that's something, I guess.

Answer (score 0):

This equation can have real and complex solutions for certain values of a. It an be considered as a Diophantine equation. To solve it we can use incomplete factorization :

$x^4-2ax^3+(a^2+1)x^2-2ax+(a^2-1)=(x^2+1)(x-a)^2-1=0$

OR:

$(x^2+1)(x-a)^2=1=1\times1=-1\times(-1)$

Now we can establish following systems of equation:

1:$\begin{cases}x^2+1=1\\(x-a)^2=1\end{cases}$

which gives $(x, a)=(0, \pm1)$ ; $(x, a)=(\pm1,(0,2))$

2:$\begin{cases}x^2+1=-1\\(x-a)^2=-1\end{cases}$

which gives $(x, a)=(a\pm i)$

also:

$a^2+2ai-1=-1\rightarrow a=0 ; a=-2i\rightarrow x=-i$;

$a^2-2ai-1=-1\rightarrow a=0 ; a=2i\rightarrow 
x=i$

Another method is to change the role of variable and constant; we may write:

$x^4-2ax^3+(a^2+1)x^2-2ax+(a^2-1)=(x^2+1)a^2-2(x^3+x)a+x^4+x^2-1=0$

$\Delta'=(x^3-x)^2-(x^2+1)(x^4+x^2-1)$

which reduces to:

$\Delta'=x^2+1$

$\Rightarrow a=\frac{(x^3+x)\pm\sqrt {x^2+1}}{x^2+1}=x\pm \frac 1{\sqrt{x^2+1}}$

For example $x=\pm \sqrt3$ gives:

$a=\sqrt 3\pm\frac 12$